# reload d3 graph when a 'dropdown menu value changes

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to get my d3.js line chart reloading when the user chooses an item in a dropdown menu, with the data corresponding to this item.

My menu is a list of stock market values:

- YHOO
- FB
- ...

For each of these, I have a JSON file with the data. 
The graph in itself is working.

I put the code in a [JSFiddle], which doesn't work because it is supposed to use d3 and knockout.js.

It may be easier to work from this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/basilesimon/10891476).

Anyway, the code past line 83 changes `newValue` for each choice in the dropdown. 
The data is stored in `yahoo.json` and `fb.json`.

How can I have the graph reloading each time the user selects a new choice in the dropdown menu with the data associated with this choice?

Thank you SO MUCH.

EDIT: temporary hack

```
/*User's stock choice*/
var viewModel = {
    choice: ["AAPL", "YHOO", "FB", "MSFT"],
    selectedChoice: ko.observable("two"), /*Knockout.js is used for having an observable array*/
};
viewModel.selectedChoice.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   console.log(newValue);
   if (newValue === "YHOO") {
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    d3.json('yahoo.json', draw);
   } else if (newValue === "FB") {
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    d3.json('fb.json', draw);
   }

});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use d3 to bind events to the dropdown menu and then call a function when an on change event occurs.  The function would go off and, in your case, grab the stock values from Yahoo.  The only real trick is getting the data out of `this`.  I ended up console logging `this` and digging through until I found `__data__`.  Using d3 means you don't need knockout for this and can remove that code from your example.

Anyway, to set this up you'll need a div to append the dropdown menu and a set of stock names.  You can use this list of stock names to create the dropdown menu as shown below.

> var names = ["AAPL", "YHOO", "FB", "MSFT"];
>
> ```
> d3.select("#dropDown")
>     .append("select")
>     .on("change", function() {
>         change(this.options[this.selectedIndex].__data__);
>     })
>     .selectAll("option")
>     .data(names).enter()
>     .append("option")
>     .text(function(d) {
>         return d;
>     });
> ```

Of course you need to setup the change function, which needs to wrap up all the variables required to do the call to Yahoo. Obviously, you'll need to pass in the stock parameter and once you've received the json back from Yahoo you'll need to call your draw function. So borrowing from your code something like this should work:

> ```
> function change(stock) {
>
>     var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
>     var startDate = '2013-09-06';
>     var endDate = '2014-03-06';
>     // NB the inclusion of the stock parameter
>     var req = encodeURIComponent('select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ("' + stock + '") and startDate = "' + startDate + '" and endDate = "' + endDate + '"');
>
>     var data = $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + req + "&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json", draw);
>
> }
> ```

You'd have to call the draw function on load otherwise you'll end up with a blank screen and also sort out transitioning from one data set to the next.