# Using Drop-down menu with D3 force layout graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to use a drop down menu with a D3 force layout graph so that when I select an option from the drop down menu, the corresponding node becomes highlighted and the name appears above the node. I am using jquery to get the value of the selected option and then want this option to match up with the correct node. Here is the jquery that I am currently using. I know I will probably have to add on to this but am not sure where to go next:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.letters').on('change',function(){
              cur_name = $('.letters').val();
              alert('The selected name is ' + cur_name);
                                            }); 
                              });
```

The alert is just for testing purposes. I have also made a jsfiddle and here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ohiobucks23/xr3uE/

I am making a much larger force layout graph with a lot more options than just A, B, and C but just made this on a smaller scale really quick for proof of concept purposes. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you give your nodes an id you can just select them in the usual way, so something like:

```
d3.select("#" + letter)
```

in your on change function.

You can also use d3 to create the dropdown menu, for instance:

```
var select = d3.select("body").append("select")
        .attr("id", "selecter")
        .on("change", mouseover);

var options = select.selectAll("option")
        .data(l);

options.enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function(d, i) {
            return d;
        })
        .text(function(d, i) {
            return d;
        });
```

Which was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780835/putting-the-country-on-drop-down-list-using-d3-via-csv-file) question.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113394/reload-d3-graph-when-a-dropdown-menu-value-changes) question might also help.

And to get you going I've hacked about with your fiddle and bumped it to [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xLb97/1/) - not I've been very lazy and just pointed the change event to the mouseover function (which I amended for the purposes of demonstrating the concept so everything is broken but ...)